# Observer pattern in Java without inheritance

Tags: java, runnable, observer-pattern

What is the problem with implementing the Observer pattern without base classes/interfaces, just with Runnable for example:

```
public ObservableClass
{
    List<Runnable> observers;
    public void add(Runnable r) { observers.add(r); }
    public void notify() { // forloop and observers[i].run(); }
}

public ObserverClass
{
    ObservableClass observable;
    public void listen()
    {
       observable.add(new Runnable() {
           @Override
            public void run() {
               // do something here
            }
       });
    }
}
```

I'm asking for problems beside if this is "ugly" or "lazy".
For example one problem I can see is that we cannot pass data to the observer directly (but if we have access to that data in Observable then we could still use it inside our RUnnable).

What are the disadvantages of using a code like that instead of creating an Observable base class and some Observer interface?

Comment: Well you can always use `Callable<T>` insteed of `Runnable`

Comment: I wouldn't use `Callable` or `Runnable` unless the implementing class was actually designed to be executed by a thread (or executor service).  One of the big advantages of Java and its classes is type safety.  That should be your first priority when designing software, making classes that actually represent different things that need to be dealt with differently by the code.

Comment: All you have essentially done is replace the typically called `Observer` interface/abstract class with the less informative and more likely to be wrongly used `Runnable`, which means you do not "implement the Observer pattern without base classes/interfaces".

Comment: @d.j.brown yes but we don't need to extend any class to make it "Observable" (specially useful if we don't have multi inheritance), and we don't need to implement any custom interface either in our Observer class, just add the method we want to execute.